# Install WordPress in subdirectory of ASP.NET CMS on Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, iis-7.5, nopcommerce

How would one go about installing WordPress in the subdirectory of another ASP.NET CMS, nopCommerce, on a Microsoft-IIS/7.5 server? Are there any particular security implications to consider? The server is running ASP.NET v4.0.30319.

Comment: I think you are playing with fire.  Backups, bindings, upgrades.  Do you want to create sub-sites for the main Nop?  A reason would help understand the context.

Comment: The blog feature in nopCommerce is very basic. It's generally considered better in terms of SEO to install a website blog in a sub folder rather than a sub directory. I want to know is it possible to install WordPress in a sub folder of nopCommerce? Or is it too much of a headache?

Comment: To my knowledge, wordpress uses PHP, so you will be running the main site as ASP.net and then have to create sub-applications (or set the subfolder as an app also), but with PHP as the engine.  Tricky, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.  I would not suggest that as a typical setup.  Also, the backup mechanism - WebDeploy, may have a problem with that config.  A worthwhile test, if you have time.